# getting error when using struct and pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

I'm testing something that we do in school. I have a struct `MyStruct` and two pointers, but when I want to work with the pointer I get this error for both pointers:

> uninitialized local variable 'p' used

```
struct MyStruct {
    int id;
    double value;
};

MyStruct *p, *q;
double z = 10;
double y = 16.17;
(*p).value = z;
(*q).value = y;
cout << (*p).value << " " << (*q).value << endl;
```

Comment: Why are you even using pointers here?

Comment: Because our teacher is going to ask us questions like "what is the result of operation p=q.." and stuff like that..

Comment: @Honza -- enter this into the search box above: "uninitialized pointer c++". Variations of this question get asked a lot. This one may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936349/where-is-memory-allocated-for-pointers-and-their-data. If you do need to ask questions like this in the future, include enough that the snippet will compile if we cut & pasted it. (Hope that wasn't too toxic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `p` and `q` pointers aren't initialized, so attempting to dereference them is undefined behaviour!

If you really want to use pointers here, make sure you have them point to valid memory. For example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int id;
    double value;
};

MyStruct *p = new MyStruct, *q = new MyStruct; // <- allocate memory with `new`
double z = 10;
double y = 16.17;
(*p).value = z;
(*q).value = y;
cout << (*p).value << " " << (*q).value << endl;

delete p; // <- free memory with `delete`
delete q;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the memory for both p and q structs. What you are doing is trying to access some pointer that doesn't point anywhere.

Add these two lines and don't forget to delete p and q when you're done working with them

```
p = new MyStruct;
q = new MyStruct;
```